# Is it possible to query the WebBrowser control whether the horizontal scrollbar is visible?

Tags: c#, winforms, dom, scrollbar, webbrowser-control

Using a [`WebBrowser` control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) in my Windows Forms application, I want to retrieve the information, whether a horizontal scrollbar is currently being shown.

E.g. I want to create a function/property, let's call it "`HasHorzontalScrollbar`", that either returns `true` or `false`:

[image]

I've tried to use Spy++ to inspect the window and I tried to read the size from the window similar the following, but I'm still unable to get meaningful values:

```
var height1 = webBrowser1.Document.Window.Size.Height;
var height2 = webBrowser1.Height;
```

**My question is:**

Is there a way to query the `WebBrowser` whether the horizontal scrollbar is currently visible?

**Edit: Solved**

Thanks to the help from [Yahia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/847363/yahia), I was able to develop a solution:

```
public bool HasHorizontalScrollbar
{
    get
    {
        var width1 = webBrowser.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Width;
        var width2 = webBrowser.Document.Window.Size.Width;

        return width1 > width2;
    }
}
```

This works in my test environment.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try

```
var height = webBrowser1.Document.Body.ScrollRectangle.Height;
```

see [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollrectangle.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, @Yahia - In my test project,the `ScrollRectangle`'s height stays constant, no matter whether a scrollbar is present or not. Am I doing something wrong here?

Comment: @UweKeim In the past this has worked fine for me... I can't test it right now... I imagine that it depends on what Windows and IE versions are in play...